# Do I lose control of a creature if the aura which granted me control of it is destroyed?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I gain control over a creature with e.g. [Hypnotic Siren](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hypnotic%20Siren).
Do I lose control over that creature if the enchantment is destroyed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Hypnotic Siren](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHypnotic%20Siren%5d) says "You control enchanted creature." This is a continuous effect that's present as long as Hypnotic Siren is on the battlefield enchanting a creature. Once it's gone, that effect goes away and you'll lose control of the creature, giving it back to whoever had it before. (In common situations, anyway - see [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/38798/409) for details.)

Since you used Hypnotic Siren as just one example, though, I should mention that not everything works that way.

If a card simply reads "Gain control of X" and doesn't mention a duration (e.g. "until end of turn"), that effect lasts indefinitely. For example, [Beguiler of Wills](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBeguiler%20of%20Wills%5d) reads:

> {T}: Gain control of target creature with power less than or equal to the number of creatures you control.

That effect lasts indefinitely; you'll get to keep the creature for the rest of the game, unless someone else has a way to gain control of it.

Comment: Do you know which rule says that the creature goes back to its previous controller? I could imagine that it goes back to its owner, instead, for instance.

Comment: @EOL That seems like a new question. This question didn't ask about multiple control-changing effects. The tl;dr is that when there's more than one such effect, they all still exist, it's just that the last one takes precedence. So if it goes away, the next-to-last one is still there.

Comment: You're right. This is elaborated upon in a thread I started after asking the question here: https://boardgamegeek.com/article/27150694#27150694

Comment: @EOL In case it was unclear, I was suggesting that you post it as a question. Questions and answers are much more useful to future readers than notes in comments. (Also often more useful than elaboration in long forum threads!)

Comment: I linked to the answer itself. I prefer not to duplicate the question on two different websites.

Comment: @EOL We definitely benefit from asking things here. Most notably, the question/answer format is much more organized and easy to find answers for future readers. Since you're not inclined to do so, I [posted the question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/38798/409) myself.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, you lose control of the creature.**

Enchantments with static abilities only work as long as the enchantment is on the battlefield. If the enchantment is destroyed, the effect immediately ends.

> 611.3. A continuous effect may be generated by the static ability of an object.

> 611.3b The effect applies at all times that the permanent generating it is on the battlefield or the object generating it is in the appropriate zone.

Logically, the reverse of that rule says that if the permanent leaves the battlefield (or generally the object leaves the appropriate zone), the effect ends.

Note that there are some cards that permanently change control of permanents, such as [Keiga, the Tide Star](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Keiga%2C%20the%20Tide%20Star) when it dies. If a control-changing effect is not the result of a static ability but the result of a one-shot spell or ability, the change of control is permanent unless the effect has a duration specified.

> 611.2a A continuous effect generated by the resolution of a spell or ability lasts as long as stated by the spell or ability creating it (such as “until end of turn”). If no duration is stated, it lasts until the end of the game.