# What happens to a permanent stolen with 'Invoke the Winds' after the thief leaves the game?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Player A steals a permanent from player B, via an effect like Invoke the Winds.

Player A leaves the game.

What happens to the stolen permanent? Does it leave the game as well, and goes in exile of its owner? Or does it go back to the battlefield under its owner's control? Or something else?

---

Related:

[What happens to a permanent I gained control over using Agent of Treachery, and I leave a multiplayer game?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/47975/what-happens-to-a-permanent-i-gained-control-over-using-agent-of-treachery-and)

In this example the card mentions

> "Agent of Treachery’s effect lasts indefinitely. It doesn’t wear off during the cleanup step, and it doesn’t expire if Agent of Treachery leaves the battlefield. In a multiplayer game, it does expire if you leave the game."

But Invoke the Winds doesn't share that ruling.

Comment: Rulings are just clarifications of how the CRs apply to a situation; the presence or absence of a ruling with things using the same wording on the card shoudn't be taken as an indication they behave differently - in fact, it's very common to reference the ruling which exists on a card using the same wording when one is absent on a particular card.

Comment: In fact, all that is covered in [the accepted answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/47976/5918) to the duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Control of the permanent goes back to player B.

What I can see in the offical rules is 800.4a, which handles a player leaving a multiplayer game. Effects that have given them control of something they don't own immediately end.

> 800.4a When a player leaves the game, all objects (see rule 109) owned by that player leave the game and any effects which give that player control of any objects or players end. Then, if that player controlled any objects on the stack not represented by cards, those objects cease to exist. Then, if there are any objects still controlled by that player, those objects are exiled. This is not a state-based action. It happens as soon as the player leaves the game. If the player who left the game had priority at the time they left, priority passes to the next player in turn order who’s still in the game.

Notably, it gives us this example:

> Example: Alex casts Act of Treason, which reads, in part, “Gain control of target creature until end of turn,” targeting Bianca’s Runeclaw Bears. If Alex leaves the game, Act of Treason’s change-of-control effect ends and Runeclaw Bears reverts to Bianca’s control.

That sounds the most like the example with Invoke the Winds.

Comment: Act of Treason lasts until end of turn though, Invoke the Winds doesn't state that. So the way I read it is that in my case there's no ongoing effect that holds control over the stolen card? Doesn't that change the situation?

Comment: Do you want to mention how to get into the situation of "Then, if there are any objects still controlled by that player, those objects are exiled."?

Comment: @JonTheMon It's covered in the [duplicate question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/47976/5918)

Comment: @Lainathiel There _is_ a continuous effect that is giving you control over the stolen card, it just lasts indefinitely.  The fact that Act of Treason's effect ends at EOT and Invoke the Winds' effect doesn't isn't relevant in this situation.